# Abstract Inner Product Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a basis for the vector space $V$ and define $\langle,\rangle$ by $\langle u,v \rangle = [u]_B \cdot [v]_B$ for $u,v \in V$. Show that $\langle,\rangle $ is an inner product on $V$.

What I know is that it must adhere the following axioms in order to be considered an inner product:

- $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle v,u \rangle$ [Symmetry axiom]
- $\langle u + v,w \rangle = \langle u, w \rangle + \langle v, w \rangle$ [Additivity axiom]
- $\langle ku +,v\rangle = k \langle v,u \rangle$ [Homogeneity axiom]
- $\langle v,v\rangle \geq 0$ [Positivity axiom]

The abstractness of this proof is throwing me off, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just check that $u \mapsto [u]_B$ is linear from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^B$. Since the dot product is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^B$ (I'm guessing the field is $\mathbb{R}$), it should be straightforward to check the axioms for $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: @AidanSims Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AidanSims's comment is awesome! However, I would like to share my 
step-by-step answer.

Let $B=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$. Given $u,v,w\in V$, write
$u=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$, $v=\sum_{i=1}^nb_iv_i$, and $w=\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i$ for some scalars
$a_i,b_i,c_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

- We have
  \begin{align}
  \left\langle u,v\right\rangle
  &=[u]_B\cdot[v]_B
  =\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\\
  &=\sum_{i=1}^nb_ia_i
  =\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =[v]_B\cdot[u]_B
  =\left\langle v,u\right\rangle.
  \end{align}
- We have
  \begin{align}
  \left\langle u+v,w\right\rangle
  &=[u+v]_B\cdot[w]_B
  =\begin{pmatrix}a_1+b_1\\a_2+b_2\\\vdots\\a_n+b_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)c_i\\
  &=\sum_{i=1}^na_ic_i+\sum_{i=1}^nb_ic_i
  =\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_n
  \end{pmatrix}+
  \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_n
  \end{pmatrix}\\
  &=[u]_B\cdot[w]_B+[v]_B\cdot[w]_B
  =\left\langle u,w\right\rangle+\left\langle v,w\right\rangle.
  \end{align}
- Given $k\in\mathbb{R}$, then we have
  \begin{align}
  \left\langle ku,v\right\rangle
  &=[ku]_B\cdot[v]_B
  =\begin{pmatrix}ka_1\\ka_2\\\vdots\\ka_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\sum_{i=1}^n(ka_i)b_i\\
  &=k\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i
  =k\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =k\left([u]_B\cdot[v]_B\right)
  =k\left\langle u,v\right\rangle.
  \end{align}
- We have
  \begin{align}
  \left\langle v,v\right\rangle
  &=[v]_B\cdot[v]_B
  =\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}\cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  =\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\geq 0.
  \end{align}

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the help! It makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: @RedShift you are welcome!:) Hope this demonstration will help you more understanding how to prove a mathematical problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is an example of a simple concept obscured by technicalities, formalism and lack of context. In a proper context, this is an excellent question. Without context and, what's worse, a hodgepodge of half-concepts, this is a recipe for confusion.

Here's one possible context to help you see this question clearly. It has little to do with the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Every inner product, as defined by the three or four requirements that you listed, has a component space representation. Just like everything else in linear algebra does, from linear combinations of vectors to linear transformations. The component space representation of things usually involves matrices and matrix operations.

As far as the inner product is concerned, the component space representation is the matrix product $x^TMy$ where $x$ and $y$ contain the components of $u$ and $v$, and $M$ has nice properties, too. The whole thing is possible because the inner product is linear in each argument (properties 2 and 3 as you listed). Furthermore, $M$ is symmetric because of property 1 and positive-definite because of property 3. (How does one calculate $M$? Simple: it's the matrix of pairwise inner products of the basis vectors.)

The converse is, naturally, also true. An operation $whatever(u,v)$ defined as $x^TMy$ for any **symmetric, positive definite** matrix $M$ is necessarily an inner product. Proving it either way is a matter of going back and forth between the properties of the matrix and the required properties of the operation to qualify as an inner product. For example, given the properties of the matrix, let's prove the symmetric property of the operation:

$whatever(u,v)=x^TMy=(x^TMy)^T=y^TM^Tx=y^TMx=whatever(v,u)$

(Justifying each step: definition; because it's a number; transpose of product; M is symmetric; definition.)

This answers part of the question that you asked, except for a general symmetric positive definite $M$. Your question asked the same thing but for $I$ instead of $M$. And instead of calling it the matrix product $x^TIy$, they called it $[u]_B\cdot[v]_B$ to make it seem like they are relating the inner product in the "physical" space with the "dot product" in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in some profound way.

As a final aside, the very concept of the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is confusing. What is it: the sum of pairwise products of the entries or length of $u$ times the length of $v$ times the cosine of the angle between them? If the former, where does it come from, how is it related to the component space representation, and is it "a" dot product or "the" dot product. If the latter, what are length and angle for n-tuples of numbers? In my opinion, it's an unnecessarily confusing way of presenting simple and elegant linear algebra concepts.